# UDP Broadcasting not working on same machine in windows 8

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am developing an application in which broadcasting is essential. I have created two projects Client and server. I am able to send broadcast message but I am not receiving in server project. My code is as follows

Server:

```
    private DatagramSocket _udpSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _udpSocket.MessageReceived += _udpSocket_MessageReceived;
       
        await _udpSocket.BindServiceNameAsync("4777");                       
    }

    void _udpSocket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
      
    }
```

Client

```
        HostName h = new HostName("255.255.255.255");
        IOutputStream outStream = await _socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(h, "4777");
       
        DataWriter de = new DataWriter(outStream);
        de.WriteByte(new byte());
        await de.StoreAsync();
        de.DetachBuffer();
```

But If on client side I replace 255.255.255.255 with local IPAddress, I can receive the message on the server.

What is the problem?

Comment: Is the server in the same network/subnet as the client PC?

Comment: Server is on the same network and both server and client are running on the same pc.

Comment: Maybe the firewall blocks the port? Did you check it? Or you can even try to replace 255.255.255.255 with the broadcast address of your network itself.

Comment: I have turned off the firewall and I have also set inbound and outbount ports, its not working.

Comment: Maybe your router is blocking broadcasts? I'm just giving clues because I did not have this myself yet.

Comment: What is the IP address/submask of both machines?

Comment: @TimVK Any router will block broadcasts to 255.255.255.255. OP: is there a router in the path?

Comment: Its working when server is running on one machine and client on another machine in same network and i dont know what happening when both are run on same machine. Even this was working in release preview, its not working in rtm.

Comment: Did you already solve the problem? I'm facing the same issue in the same environment like you (client/server on the same pc).

Comment: @Alexander u need to use it on different machine.

Comment: @nucleons thank you for the info - so i have to support tcp too, to solve my problem. OK that's fine - thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem when I run my server via Task Scheduler and start up my client by double-clicking on its icon.  They both are on the same machine, but I don't receive broadcasts.  If I manually open them both up I can, but just not when the server is started via Task Scheduler.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just run it on two different machines.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember well my network 101 class, when you do a broadcast, the packet is not sent back to you, only to all other computers on the network (I might be wrong tough). Also, like TimVK said in his comment, you should try using your network's broadcast address instead of the general broadcast (for the network `192.168.0.0/24` (mask `255.255.255.0`) the broadcast would be `192.168.0.255`