# Can't connect to WinRT server from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, tcpclient

My WinRT server code looks like this

```
public class Server
{
    StreamSocketListener networkListener;

    public Server()
    {
        networkListener = new StreamSocketListener();
        networkListener.ConnectionReceived += networkListener_ConnectionReceived;
    }

    void networkListener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        //never gets called
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        await networkListener.BindServiceNameAsync("51114");   
    }
```

}

The port doesn't matter, I checked that it is not in use, and tried a few others.

My WPF code looks like this

```
    private async void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 51114);
        //client.Connect("localhost", 51114);
    }
```

I've tried "localhost", "127.0.0.1", and the actual local IP of my computer.

The port has been allowed through the firewall.

From what I can tell, the server is starting in the WinRT application, no exception is thrown, and netstat -a  reveals that I am listening on port 51114.

When the WPF application tries to connect, I get the following error

> An exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

The ErrorCode in the exception is 10060

Answer (score 1):

I remember a thread with quite a similar issue on udp broadcasting: [UDP Broadcasting not working on same machine in windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459091/udp-broadcasting-not-working-on-same-machine-in-windows-8#comment22478300_12459091)

I tried having websocket client and server on the same machine (see the comments of the above thread) and it didn't work. I'm sorry, but i don't know why (it worked only on different machines).

Comment: Well that's terribly inconvenient for development. I am not going to mark this as the answer yet, I want to see if anyone else chimes in with a workaround. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I know this is over a year later, but was this ever resolved?